# Expected value of round robin scores and ranks

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, expectation

Suppose you have $n$ players play a round robin tournament. A win adds 1 to the winning score of a player while a loss adds nothing. After the round robin tournament is finished the players are assigned ranks based on their scores, with ties being broken at random, the top player receiving a rank of $n-1$ and the bottom player receiving a rank of $0$. What is the relationship between the expected value of the $\textbf{score}$ of player $i$ and the expected value of the  $\textbf{rank}$ of player $i$?

Results of a sample tournament with 5 players: $scores=(3,3,2,1,1)$ and $ranks=(3,4,2,1,0)$

Addition information: A player $i$ has an attribute $\lambda_i$. The probability that player i beats player $j$ in a game is $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}$.

Numerical simulations suggest that the two ($\textbf{score}$ and $\textbf{rank}$) are perfectly correlated if taken across all the players, but I don't know how to prove this. Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the expected value of the rank of player $i$.  It is what it is.  You are claiming that the expected value of the score matches the rank.  Look at two players $i$ and $j$ with attributes $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$. The expected score for $i$ is $\sum_{k\neq i}\frac {\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\lambda_k}$  If $\lambda_i\lt\lambda_j$, the expected score for $i$ is clearly less than that for $j$, term by term.

Comment: "You don't want the expected value of the rank of player i. It is what it is." I don't quite understand what you mean by this. Can you please clarify?

Comment: This is input data.  The claim is that the expected scores match the ranks, no matter what the attributes are.

Comment: Just to clarify that we are talking about the same things: when I say "rank", I mean "rank" after a tournament. Like the score, "rank" is a random variable, and hence it makes sense to talk about its expectation.

Comment: Really there are two claims, which support each other.  The ordering of expected scores matches that of the attributes and the ordering of the expected ranks matches the attributes.  Going back to the attributes makes it pretty easy.

Comment: Yes what you say is correct. But I am interested in the exact relationship between the expected score and the expected rank

Comment: You asked for perfect correlation and it is there.  Now it sounds like you want some functional relationship?  If so, it will depend on the distribution of attributes.

Comment: All attributes originate from the same normal distribution.